# VB.Net login form, can't connect to Access database?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access

I am creating an application and I am having difficulty at the first hurdle. I have created a login form consisting of a username and password text box where the the entries must be matched to a record in the database to proceed.

The application is created in Visual Studio Express 2013 and the database is created in Access 2013.
When I attempt to compile I am getting the following error message.

An unhandled exception of type **'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'** occurred in **System.Data.dll**.

Additional information: Syntax error in FROM clause.

The code for the page is below

```
Imports System

Imports System.Data

Imports System.Data.OleDb

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class frm_1_Login

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Login.Click
    ' Check if username or password is empty
    If txt_Username.Text = "" Or txt_Password.Text = "" Then
        lbl_LoginWarning.Visible = True
    Else
        'Connect To Database
        Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Non Conformance\NonConformance.accdb"

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserName ='" & txt_Username.Text & "' AND UserPassword = '" & txt_Password.Text & "'"

        Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)

        'open database connection
        sqlCom.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()



        ' Try


        Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

        If sqlRead.Read() Then
            frm_2_MainMenu.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            'if user enters wrong username and password combination display error message
            lbl_LoginWarning.Visible = True
            'clear all fields
            txt_Password.Text = ""
            txt_Username.Text = ""
            'Focus in username field
            txt_Username.Focus()
        End If
        ' Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to Database..", "Database Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        'End Try
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

When its throwing me the error message it is highlighting this line of code afterwards

```
Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()
```

I have copied the query into access and that works fine.

I am unsure what is causing this and any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

`User` is a `reserved word` in Access: [Reserverd words in access](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe).
You must incapsulate reserved words with `[]` to make em work.

Your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE UserName ='" & txt_Username.Text & "' AND UserPassword = '" & txt_Password.Text & "'
```

And please read up on the use of parameters in your queries, it'll save you much problems later on.
[Here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/26/parameter-queries-in-asp-net-with-ms-access) is some handy info on queries and parameters for OleDb (Access)

Comment: Jesus christ..... I have changed field names and all sorts, encapsulated the field names but it never occured to me to encapsulate the table name.... Thanks so much for the response!

Comment: No problem! have a great day :) Feel free to approve it as answer